# linq and parallelism - SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm encountering an issue with LINQ To Entities.

If I run my LINQ query then it use **Parallelism (Gather Streams and Reparation Stream)** in the execution plan which causes lots of CXPACKET waits.

But if I run the LINQ translated query (which I got via the ToTraceString function) directly to my sql server then the execution plan doesn't contain the parallelism.

Why is there a difference in regarding to the parallelism of the SQL when running it via LINQ vs the SQL query itself?

How can I overcome this issue? I want that my LINQ query will run the same way as when I run its SQL directly.

Example of the execution plans:

using LINQ:
[image: using linq]

SQL directly:

[image: without linq - sql directly]

I can publish my SQL query, but I don't think it can help here...

Comment: I had the same issue - running the stored procedure from web app caused timeouts, while running it directly from SQL managment studio was fast enough; in that case recompilation of stored procedures solved it. If I were you I would try to look into compiled queries - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896297.aspx (dunno if that would help though)

Comment: Try running the following command `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` followed by `sp_updatestats` and see if the problem still exist.

Comment: Have you run SQL Profiler against the DB to see what SQL is actually being executed by Linq? Also, is there anything funny in the connection string the client uses?

Answer (score 0):

Are the CXPACKET waits actually a problem?

When SQL Server receives a query it optimizes it.  If the estimated cost of the query is greater then the Cost Threshold for Parallelism it will consider a parallel query.  It is always possible to raise this threshold if too many queries are being parallelized.

I would like to know if there is any difference between the entity framework query and your query that could push the estimated cost up.

Either way, CXPATCKET waits are NOT a problem.  They are a natural part of any parallel query and we aren't paying extra money for quad core servers with multiple threads so we can run everything in a series.  Another thing to check is the network.

When streaming IO over a network this can take more time if you are returning a bunch of results.  That is why running a query in SQL Server Management studios can return quickly but your query from another server can take awhile.